# Spearman's rank correlation

Tags: r, plot, correlation

i'm writing a script that reads two .txt file in two vectors. After that I want to make a Spearman's rank correlation and plot the result.
The first vectors value's length is 12-13 characters (e.g. 7.3445555667 or 10.3445555667) and the second vectors value's length is one character (e.g. 1 or 2).

The code:

```
vector1 <- read.table ("D:...path.../mytext1.txt", header=FALSE)
vector2 <- read.table ("D:...path.../mytext2.txt", header=FALSE)
cor.coeff = cor(vector1 , vector2 , method = "spearman")
cor.test(vector1 , vector2 , method = "spearman")
plot(vector1.var, vector2.var)
```

The .txt files contain only numeric values.

I'm getting two errors, the first in line 4 it's like " 'x' have to be a numeric vector"
and the second error occurs in line 5 it's like "object vector 1.var couldn't be found"

I also tried

```
 plot(vector1, vector2)
```

instead of

```
 plot(vector1.var, vector2.var)
```

But then there's an error like "Error in stripchart.default (x1,...) : invalid plot-method

The implementation is orientated at http://www.gardenersown.co.uk/Education/Lectures/R/correl.htm#correlation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I doubt `vector1` and `vector2` are vectors. Reading `?read.table` we note in the **Value** section:

> Value:
>
> ```
>     A data frame (‘data.frame’) containing a representation of the
>     data in the file.
> ```
>
> ....

So even if your two text files contain just a single variable, the two objects read in will be data frames with a single component each.

Secondly, your data files don't contain headers so R will make up a variable name. I haven't tested this but IIRC your the variables in `vector1` and `vector2` will both be called `X1`. Do `head(vector1)` and the same on `vector2` (or `names(vector1)`) to see how your objects look in R.

I can see **why** you might think `vector1.var` might work, but you should realise that as far as R was concerned it was looking for an object named `vector1.var`. The `.` is just any other character in R object names. If you meant to use `.` as a subsetting or selection operator, then you need to read up on subsetting operators in R. These are `$` and `[` and `[[`. See for example the [R Language Definition manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Indexing) or the [R manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Index-vectors).

I suspect you could just change your code to:

```
vector1 <- read.table ("D:...path.../mytext1.txt", header=FALSE)[, 1]
vector2 <- read.table ("D:...path.../mytext2.txt", header=FALSE)[, 1]
cor.coeff <- cor(vector1 , vector2 , method = "spearman")
cor.test(vector1 , vector2 , method = "spearman")
plot(vector1, vector2)
```

But I am supposing quite a bit about what is in your two text files...

Comment: Also, the usual checks need to be made that R hasn't converted data to factors etc. See `str()` as per @Maiasaura 's Answer too.

Answer (score 5):

`str` is a very useful function (see `?str` for more) that one should use often, especially to verify `R` object types. A quick `str(vector1)` and `str(vector2)` will tell you if those columns were read as characters instead of numeric. If so, then use `as.numeric(vector1)` to typecast the data in each vector.

Also, `names(vector1)` and `names(vector2)` will tell you what the column names are and likely resolve your plotting issue.